# Roblox Studio (Tried Gates) The Value doesn`t change

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried a Gates Script but the script works fine but the 2nd Remote Event doesnt like to fire. It does nothing.

--This Works Fine

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("HalloweenGatesTakeMoney")
local Price = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Price").Value

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(player)
    script.Parent.Parent.Visible = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Shadow.Visible = false
    local GateName = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Gate").Value
    GateName:Destroy()
    remoteEvent:FireServer(Price)
end)
```

--But this does nothing

```
remoteEvent2.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, Price)
    player.EventMoney.Sweets.Value = player.EventMoney.Sweets.Value - Price
    wait(1)
    if player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").Frame.Buy.GateValueName == "HauntedEntrance" then
        player:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").HauntedEntrance.Value = true
    elseif player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").Frame.Buy.GateValueName == "PumpkinCave" then 
        player:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").PumpkinCave.Value = true
    elseif player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").Frame.Buy.GateValueName == "HauntedBiome" then
        player:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").HauntedBiome.Value = true
    elseif player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").Frame.Buy.GateValueName == "GiantPumpkin"  then
        player:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").GiantPumpkin.Value = true
    end
end)
```

--Full script of above

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local remoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates")
local remoteEvent2 = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("HalloweenGatesTakeMoney")

remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, Price, GateName, GateValue)
    if player.EventMoney.Sweets.Value >= Price then
        player.PlayerGui.HalloweenGates.Frame.Visible = true
        player.PlayerGui.HalloweenGates.Shadow.Visible = true
        player.PlayerGui.HalloweenGates.Frame.Price.Text = "This Gate costs "..Price.." Sweets"
        player.PlayerGui.HalloweenGates.Frame.Buy.Gate.Value = GateName
        player.PlayerGui.HalloweenGates.Frame.Buy.Price.Value = Price
        player.PlayerGui.HalloweenGates.Frame.Buy.GateValueName.Value = GateValue
    end
end)

remoteEvent2.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, Price)
    player.EventMoney.Sweets.Value = player.EventMoney.Sweets.Value - Price
    wait(1)
    if player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").Frame.Buy.GateValueName == "HauntedEntrance" then
        player:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").HauntedEntrance.Value = true
    elseif player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").Frame.Buy.GateValueName == "PumpkinCave" then 
        player:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").PumpkinCave.Value = true
    elseif player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").Frame.Buy.GateValueName == "HauntedBiome" then
        player:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").HauntedBiome.Value = true
    elseif player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").Frame.Buy.GateValueName == "GiantPumpkin"  then
        player:WaitForChild("HalloweenGates").GiantPumpkin.Value = true
    end
end)
```

--Here's where I fire the remoteEvent2 event

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("HalloweenGatesTakeMoney")
local Price = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Price").Value

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(player) 
    script.Parent.Parent.Visible = false 
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Shadow.Visible = false

    local GateName = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Gate").Value
    GateName:Destroy() 

    remoteEvent:FireServer(Price)
end)
```

Comment: Do you have any code that calls `remoteEvent2:FireServer`?

Comment: https://ibb.co/QCxwvGs

Comment: Instead of posting this as a comment, you should edit your question to include this code. It will make it a heck of a lot easier to read.

Comment: sorry im new to this